# Vertex Locking in Place

Tags: armature

Whenever I move my knee joint in pose mode (via IK bone) there seems to always be one vertex that does not move at all. It does not have any weight assigned to it (but it had 100% with automatic weights oddly, but I removed it). I didn't do anything special with locking the vertice there in the past, and I'm curious to know how to somehow "unlock it" so that it moves with the rest of the mesh.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You said: "It does not have any weight assigned to it". This make me think that it has no reason to move as there is no relation between the bone and the vertex itself. Could you clarify this aspect?

Comment: I meant that it was at the default weight, here's a picture of the weight painting, there's another disconnected vertex, but I think that's just with my weight painting. https://i.imgur.com/1ISw7sR.png